# Possible .obb virus?

Tags: antivirus

I have a strange problem. I've been searching for a possible solution for a long time, finding nothing, so here am I.
So, I was trying to transfer an .obb file from the Pc into my Android phone directory  (Phone/Android/Data/),
. I managed to transfer this  file, but changed my mind and I tried to delete it . The fact is that since then nothing has been able to remove it. I tried all kinda of removal programs, command prompt related deleting solutions, ecc.  The file does not allow me to change  security from "only read" to "write", the options are like frozen. Plus, the file is visible from the Pc but not from the phone . I even tried cut and paste, but nothing. Last thing : if I copy the file from the pc I am able to delete the copy, but not the original one .

In conclusion : This seems to me some kind Android virus , and the fact that I can't delete it makes me mad. Does any of you here have an idea on what's going on here? 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: It is easy to drop an .obb onto your phone, but android detects it as a possible system file and CAN make it undeleteable under certain circumstances (citation needed)

Comment: From your Android's command line, issue `lsattr /path/to/your/file.obb`, and tell us the output, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most android file mangers won't show files starting with a period (.) By default. But you can view them by Settings > Display Settings > Show hidden files. (In ES file explorer).
When the file is visible in phone try to delete it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login into your PC as an administrator, (windows), rename the file by changing the extension es:
From file.obb to file.txt and see if after  you can delete it. 
Make sure the folder where the file reside or the file itself is not opened by any other apps other than your file explorer.